# mod_rewrite.c is not found in apache 2.4.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I do not find mod_rewrite.c in apache 2.4.4; but I have enabled mod_rewrite. Is it required to run the following .htaccess file, because I am getting error 500 internal server error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /phpcs5
# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite category pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Depart
mentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&Cate
goryId=$2 [L]
# Rewrite department pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&Pag
e=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1 [L]
# Rewrite subpages of the home page
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L]
# Rewrite product details pages
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?ProductId=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you've got tons of stray newlines, which will 100% cause 500 server errors:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /phpcs5
# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite category pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&CategoryId=$2 [L]
# Rewrite department pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&Page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1 [L]
# Rewrite subpages of the home page
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L]
# Rewrite product details pages
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?ProductId=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```